# Vertically align within textpos

Tags: vertical-alignment

I need to center align some text center in textpos.

A and +++ should be center align.

My minimal coding:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\begin{document}
  \begin{textblock*}{10cm}(5cm,3cm)%
  \begin{minipage}[c]{5cm}
    \Huge A \tiny +++
    \end{minipage}
  \end{textblock*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So you want the `A` and `+++` to be vertically centred?

Comment: What is supposed to be centred with respect to what?

Comment: @werner, cfr: yes, A and +++ need vertically center. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easiest to adjust via [`adjustbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox)'s `valign=c` option:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

{\Huge A \tiny +++}

\bigskip

\adjustbox{valign=c}{\Huge A}
\adjustbox{valign=c}{\tiny +++}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use a tabular instead of the minipage. As added benefit, with `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}`, you get perfect kerning:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\begin{document}
  \begin{textblock*}{10cm}(5cm,3cm)%
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
    \begin{tabular}{m{0.5cm}m{0.5cm}}
    \Huge A &\vfill\tiny +++\vfill\\
    \end{tabular}
  \end{textblock*}
\end{document}
```